# Adding jQuery code to wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add the following code to Wordpress but it doesn't seem to work. The same code in a fiddle works.

Please help.

```
$(".box").hover(

function (e) {
$('.box').not(this).addClass('grey')

}, // over
function (e) {
$('.box').removeClass('grey')

} // out
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap it in the noConflict mode. Like:

```
jQuery(function($){
// Your jQuery code here, using the $
});
```

See: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

So, that would boil down to

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(".box").hover( function (e) {
         $('.box').not(this).addClass('grey');    
    }, // over
    function (e) {
         $('.box').removeClass('grey');    
    } // out
);
});
```